# Creating Accordion from first element of sibling elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, accordion

I am trying to create an accordion (either pure CSS or javascript/jquery). I have a list of links inside a span but need the accordion to work onclick of the first element inside this span and expand its following siblings like below:

```
<span class="pager">
   <a href="#" class="pager-active">Header</a>
   <a href="#" class="">Service 1</a>
   <a href="#" class="">Service 2</a>
</span>
```

Here is a jsfiddle example of my setup.

https://jsfiddle.net/wb590xs3/7/

Edit: I cannot change this HTML structure as this is a slider and need these hrefs to be on the same level.

Comment: what you have tried...?

Comment: @Bhuwan I know how to create normal accordions like: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion but not with using the first sibling as the expander

Answer (score 1):

Did you try seeing Bootstrap collapse plugin? Just check [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/)

Answer (score 0):

With using Jquery, You can do accordion with this documentation [jQuery Accordion.](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Example

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  } );
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. 
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
    purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
    velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. 
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm looking to expand the sibling of the first link in my example. Not a general accordion. It would be like clicking on the h3 section 1 and expanding the h3 section 2 element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this pure CSS way:

```
<style>
  .pager > a {display: block;}
  .pager div {display: none;}
  .pager div:target {display: block;}
</style>
<div class="pager">
  <a href="#showServices">Header</a>   
  <div id="showServices">
    <a href="#">Service 1</a>
    <a href="#">Service 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.